# CountUp Function failing to increment from 0 to inputted time

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval

The details and code of this issue are as follows:

**Problem:**
The countUp function runs with no errors, but the UI displays the number inputted, and nothing before it.

**Current Approach:**

```
 const countUp = () => {
  let inputTime = document.getElementById("input").value; // 5
  console.log(inputTime);

  if (inputTime != 0) { // 5 != 0
    document.getElementById("countupClock").innerHTML = 0;
    let run = run => { // 5 > 0
      let clock = document.getElementById("countupClock");
      clock.value = clock.value < inputTime ? clock.value++ : inputTime;
      clock.innerHTML = clock.value;
     }
    setInterval(run(), 3000);
    } else {
      clearInterval(run);
    };
  }
```

This is what I have so far for the actual CountUp function.

The Click Event is handled here:

```
// Begin Countup:
let btn = document.getElementById("enterTime");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("New Time Entered");
  countUp();
});
```

Then this is the HTML:

```
          <html>
          <body>
            <div class="controls">
                    <p id="countup">Countup</p>
                </div>
    
            <div class="center-controls">
                <input type="number" id="input" placeholder="Enter a number"> 
            </input>
            </div>
            <div class="right-controls">
                <button id="enterTime">START</button>
            </div>      
        </div>
    </main>
        <div class="clocksContainer">
        <!-- Displays Time counting down  -->
    
            <span id="countupClock"></span>
            
        <!-- A Field that allows you to enter a time to countup from -->
        </div>
    
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Expected Output:**
The Number on the UI should increment from 0, to the users inputted number. In this case, 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `clock` variable is a span element, it doesn't have `value` property. Simply doing `clock.innerHTML++` will increment the displayed counter value. Also you should be saving the `setInterval` value and using it inside `clearInterval`.

```js
const countUp = () => {
  let interval;
  let inputTime = document.getElementById('input').value; // 5
  console.log(inputTime);

  if (inputTime != 0) {
    document.getElementById('countupClock').innerHTML = 0;
    let run = () => {
      let clock = document.getElementById('countupClock');
      if (clock.innerHTML < inputTime) {
        clock.innerHTML++;
        console.log('Counter value:', clock.innerHTML);
      } else {
        clearInterval(interval);
        console.log('Cleared interval');
      }
    };
    interval = setInterval(run, 1000);
  }
};
```

Comment: Nice, I will give this a try and get back to you.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for this response, unfortunately after implementing this, I am only able to count up to 9. Any number inputted that is higher than this, cancels out at 2.

I am going to review SetInterval in-depth to see why this may be happening.

Comment: The above solution only goes as high as 9. Is there any particular reason for this limitation? @sspathare97

Comment: As is often the way with me, I need to make a cry for help before I get the answer. After revisiting this this morning, about 30 minutes work and I figured it out. The issue is the way I was validating the values. I changed from < to !=  and now everything works as expected. Thanks again for the code solution. I had to change the second item you had as less than too in order for it to work: "if (clock.innerHTML < inputTime) {"